# Why am I getting a blank page after the contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, pdftex, blank-page

I'm using the book class to write a thesis and I keep getting a blank page appearing in between the table of contents and chapter 1. I've reduced my .tex file as far as I can to find the problem. My only clue so far is that if I remove the deceleration, the blank page goes away too. However, it's absolutely necessary that I include this information. How do I remove this unwanted blank page but keep all the sections of my thesis that I need?
Here's the .tex file I'm using that's causing me the problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,11pt]{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=40mm,right=25mm,top=20mm,bottom=40mm,includehead,includefoot,headheight=15pt]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\date{2018}

\usepackage{titling}
\pretitle{%
  \begin{center}
  \vspace{-5.0cm}
  \includegraphics[width=8cm]{logo} \\[15mm]
  \end{center}
  \begin{center}
  \LARGE
}
\posttitle{\end{center}}

\title{\textbf{Thesis Title goes here}\vspace{5mm}}
\author{Name}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\frontmatter

%%%% Declaration %%%%
\topskip0pt
\vspace*{\fill}
\noindent
\begin{quote}
\centering
    This thesis is the result of the author's original research. It has been composed by the author and has not been previously submitted for examination which has led to the award of a degree. \\[5pt]
    The copyright of this thesis belongs to the author under the terms of the United Kingdom Copyright Acts as qualified by University Regulation 3.50. Due acknowledgement must always be made of the use of any material contained in, or derived from, this thesis. \\[5pt]
\end{quote}
\vspace{10mm}
    Signed: \\
    Date:
\vspace*{\fill}
%%%% Declaration %%%%

\tableofcontents
\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}
This is the introduction to my thesis.

\end{document}
```

Thanks.

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) in book all chapters start on an odd numbered page (the right hand page if you think of it as a paper book opened in front of you. So if the table of contents ends on an odd page (say it is just one page), then latex has to insert a blank page for the chapter to start on the next odd page. This is standard behaviour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably the `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` commands are creating the problem.

So, how about using `\pagenumbering{roman}` and `\pagenubering{arabic}` instead (in the appropriate places)--

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,openany,11pt]{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=40mm,right=25mm,top=20mm,bottom=40mm,includehead,includefoot,headheight=15pt]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\date{2018}

\usepackage{titling}
\pretitle{%
\begin{center}
\vspace{-5.0cm}
\includegraphics[width=8cm]{logo} \\[15mm]
\end{center}
\begin{center}
\LARGE
}
\posttitle{\end{center}}

\title{\textbf{Thesis Title goes here}\vspace{5mm}}
\author{Name}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
%\frontmatter
\pagenumbering{roman}

%%%% Declaration %%%%
\topskip0pt
\vspace*{\fill}
\noindent
\begin{quote}
\centering
    This thesis is the result of the author's original research. It has been composed by the author and has not been previously submitted for examination which has led to the award of a degree. \\[5pt]
    The copyright of this thesis belongs to the author under the terms of the United Kingdom Copyright Acts as qualified by University Regulation 3.50. Due acknowledgement must always be made of the use of any material contained in, or derived from, this thesis. \\[5pt]
\end{quote}
\vspace{10mm}
    Signed: \\
    Date:
\vspace*{\fill}
%%%% Declaration %%%%

\tableofcontents
%\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
This is the introduction to my thesis.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, That's worked really well.

It did give numbers to some chapters (abstract, acknowledgements) before the contents page (removed in the .tex file I posted for clarity) but this was easily overcome using \chapter*{} rather than \chapter{}

Comment: @LewisReid That's an interesting update !